# I want to make height of the sidebar responsive with the height of content

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress

So I want to make the sidebar adoptive with the content. I mean when there will come more posts the more ad boxes will appear but for now some of those should disappear so that the sidebar height matches with the content height. As I am using same widget for all pages so it is making problem. So is it possible to make the sidebar height adoptive with the content block ? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
var c2Height = $('.column-2').height(),
    adHeight = 0,
    ads = $('aside .block-content ul')
    remove = false;

ads.children().each(function() {
    if(remove){
        $(this).remove();
    } else {
        adHeight += $(this).height();

        if(adHeight > c2Height){
            remove = true;
            $(this).remove();
        }
    }
});
```

This code calculates how much space there is available for adverts and removes any ads that fall outside of the column. Doing it this way means the last advert isn't cut off like it is when using `overflow: hidden;`

Comment: I used your given code by customizing and it is almost near to the solution of my problem but a little problem. I think it is happening due to the Iframe of FB Likebox. For example see this page: http://pearlandsports.com/other-sports/ .Do you have any idea for this please ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('aside').css({
    height: parseInt(  $('.block-content').outerHeight()  ), 
    overflow: 'hidden'
 });
```

You can accomplish it with the code above I provided, however, instead of using `aside` and `.block-content`, what is basicall your posts wrapper, add there some ID attributes.

**EDIT:**
sorry to confuse you

Comment: I ment that you have the sidebar HTML structure like `section > aside > div > ul` I just thought that of that as a little bit complicated

Comment: I used it with customizing the tag and class but making a little problem. I think there needs a use of position.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
var mheight=jQuery('.loop').height();
jQuery('section.column-2').css({'max-height':mheight,'overflow':'hidden'});
```